# How to make CDateTimeCtrl have a string as default value?

Tags: winapi, mfc, windows-controls

I am using MFC CDateTimeCtrl in VS2010.
It seems it always has a datetime value showed, default one is today.
I want sort of customizing it. 
Would it be possible that to make it show a string say "no date selected" when it shows up first time? After that, when the end user picks up a date, show the corresponding date.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying control supports "No value" but presents a checkbox allowiing a data to be specified (or not).

Comment: You are right, the attribute style DTS_SHOWNONE can basically do the work for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to create your own custom control or subclass the CDateTimeCtrl and override its behaviour

Comment: Do you know which specific behavior should it be override?
I have tried OnPaint OnNcPaint OnEraseBkgnd but no success.